# Restoring sharded Mongodb does not include information on shards

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongodump, mongorestore

I am using mongodump and mongorestore for taking the backup and recovering the MongoDB sharded cluster 3.2. ( 3 node cluster)

I have created a database called "testing" which has a collection named "collection1" and "collection2" 
I have then enabled sharding on the "testing" database and sharded the collections "collection1" and "collection2".

I then tried taking the backup using 
mongodump -d testing --out /backups/shard
Backup worked fine.

Next, I have dropped the database "testing"

Now I tried to restore it back using mongorestore.
mongorestore -d "testing" /backups/shard/testing/
Restored completed.

Although the database and its collections were restored. I see that sharding is not enabled in the restored database.
How to retain the sharded information of a particular database so that after the restore operation, the collection should be in the same sharded state.